# Why I cant submit script from <input type="text"> block?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser

I am sending all form info by POST method and I want to directly print them on the screen. And when I submit

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <b>Hello</b> <script>alert('Hello World')</script>"
```

into the input block then I see on the screen printed "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" then bold "Hello" and that's it. Where does script goes? Is it a protection that PHP implements???

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with Javascript. It will not strip anything unless you do it yourself, or have a webserver/php security module which does so. Have you looked at the source of the page? Obvious the html is being interpreted, since you say Hello is coming out bold. Have you verified that the javascript bit is actually not there?

Comment: Please show your code. Question isn't constructive.

Comment: Are you using any kind of PHP framework?

Comment: That is generally bad security to allow this without any checks...

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors or warnings in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I know ASP.NET, by default, protects against these sorts of XSS attacks - Maybe PHP does something similar?

Comment: @Narek: Did you even look into the HTML sourcecode?

Comment: @hakre The code is written by me and there is no need to look to source-code. What part I need to pay attention to especially?

Comment: @ Ayman Safadi No I don't use any PHP framework just pure PHP.

Comment: @Mufasa I don't know where to look for JavaScrept errors.

Comment: @Narek: Well if you actually don't know what HTML code is good for, how *could* the script that you write produce a predictable result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your PHP version and `magic_quotes_gpc` value. It escapes all REQUEST data. This value should be 'Off'. In PHP 5.3 `magic_quotes_gpc` is deprectaed.

Comment: That value is off in php.ini: magic_quotes_gpc = Off

Answer (score 1):

php does not have native protection against these attacks but sites are supposed to implement these protections

in practice any malicious code will be escaped by the php script

edit:

```
echo strip_tags($_POST['data'], "<b><i><u>");
```

Comment: You don't know about `magic quotes`

Comment: No, trying to attack my code just :) I know that no one will believe though it is the truth :)

Comment: magic quotes are deprecated, and by the way they will not clean up malicious html, they just escape " ' characters